# how to change svn commit path through hooks and python

Tags: python, svn, hook, svn-hooks

everyone. 
Due to lose manual document about python svn api. I can't solve this issues.

The detail is, when someone commit svn something to repository "/repo/prj1". But, I wang to change these content commit to other place, ie, "/repo/prj2". I found many examples about python svn script, and try to do this using hooks. But, I can't solve this issue.

Can anyone help me? Thanks first!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tested so far?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2012? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as understand the case you can't do this.

See [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks):

> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show restraint: **do not modify a
>   commit transaction using hook scripts**. While it might be tempting to
>   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
>   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
>   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
>   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
>   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
>   surprising and unexpected behavior. **Instead of modifying the
>   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements**. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.

Comment: Your help is so quick, thanks. It's very helpful for me. Thank u.